# Finding all value assignments to tree where paths to each node have unique elements

Tags: tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a tree and I need to assign a value to each node such that for each node the path from that node to the root has no repeated values. I'm trying to generate all value assignments for a set tree and store them. I haven't been able to work out or find a decent algorithm to sequentially generate these trees. Any direction or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You want all the possible solutions? This is a lot... If all you want is one just give unique id/value to each node. If you want to use minimal number of values then O(logn) is you limit

Comment: I need to do some comparisons between those graphs and some other stuff, it's a lot but I need to see them all.

Comment: Do you have range for possible value? As [1...n]? (when `n` is the number of node in tree `T`)

Comment: It would likely be ranging from [1...n] where n is up to 2 times the depth of the tree.

Comment: So [1..2*log(n)]. Do you have any time complexity constrains?

Comment: Not really, I can run this long term, just something that won't take years.

Comment: So why not brute force - `O(4*n*logn^n)` - just generate all option and delete all the one with repeated values

Comment: See I was having trouble with trying to generate those specifically, it never occurred to me to just build everything and filter out the ones that don't work. Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this algorithm:

1. start from root and array of [1...m] as option-array.
2. for each option: choose one and assign to root
3. call recursive after remove that option on all children

Maybe this pseudo code will explain it better:

```
function assign(root, options) {
    for each options as option:
        assign root with option
        newOptions = options - option // remove newly assign value
        for each root->childs as child:
            call assign(child, newOptions) //recursive call after removing current option
} 

options = [1...m]
assign(root, options)
```

This is better complexity then the brute force method

Hope that help!